# Are LC circuits preferred as series or parallel? Why?

Tags: electric-circuits

Are LC circuits preferred as series or parallel?
I recently studied about LC circuits in parallel and asked my tutor about whether the inductor and capacitor could be connected in series. He said it could be done, and added that it was more "complex" to learn at high school level. Why so?

Comment: Preferred for *what*?

Comment: Actually, in microwave (RF) engineering series resonance is preferred because the dominant loss mechanism in the resonator is the series resistance of the inductor, and if the resonator is connected to a given load then the latter can be modified to account for the loss resistance and have the proper impedance. This is standard practice for example in tunable filter design using 90deg couplers. For a "narrow" bandwidth the same can be done for a parallel resonator but not as precisely and easily.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "preferred" type of LC circuit. How to wire your circuit depends on how you want your circuit to work.

Notably the impedance is different in the two cases, while the resonant frequency is the same according to Wikipedia. If you have a look at the equations they present you can quickly see that in terms of what the two kinds circuits do to the frequency content of a signal is opposite of each other: One acts as a band-pass filter (the serial one), which reduces the amplitude of all waves, or wave components, that is not close to a specific frequency, while the the other one acts as a band-stop filter (the parallel one), which reduces the amplitude of all waves, or wave components, that are close to a specific frequency.

I'm guessing he said it was more complex because the math is different for the two cases, but I don't see what is more complex about one or the other.

The Wikipedia article has a couple of related deductions that might help you understand the differences; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit